# Counting intersections between two line layers using pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis, line, intersection, pyqgis-3, count

I want to count intersections between two line layers using pyqgis. First layer connects two points (Memorylayer_VL / Connections), the second one represents streets (lines_layer / Streets). I need to figure out how many times Connectionlines intersects with a Street. Note that the streets can have curves. So I also need to count, if a line crosses the same street more than once!

Thats where I am struggling to find a good logic how I could implement this. Anyone has a brilliant idea how this could be done? Thats what I have so far... It only counts if a street has been crossed, but not how many times.

```
    for tmp_line_feat in Memorylayer_VL.getFeatures():
        for streets in lines_layer.getFeatures():
            counter = 0
            if tmp_line_feat.geometry().intersects(streets.geometry()):
                counter = counter + 1
                attr = {5:counter}
                Memorylayer_PR.changeAttributeValues({ tmp_line_feat.id() : attr })
```

Example:

[image]

I need to know for each connection line, how many times a street has been crossed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out I just needed to make some minor adjustments in the code and especially, just **explode the streets before**... Then this works just fine:

```
    for tmp_line_feat in Memorylayer_VL.getFeatures():
        counter = 0
        for streets in lines_layer.getFeatures():                
            if tmp_line_feat.geometry().intersects(streets.geometry()):
                counter = counter + 1
            attr = {5:counter}
            Memorylayer_PR.changeAttributeValues({ tmp_line_feat.id() : attr })
```